# Retrieving unknown column names from dynamic objects C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic

I am being given a list of dynamic objects (the results of a SQL query). 
I can access any value of a specific element if I know the name of the column to access. However there are an unknown number of columns with unknown names.

How can I generate a list of the column names from the dynamic objects? 
I'm trying to avoid querying the DB again for information I should already have in this list.
If I can get a list of strings with the column names of this table I should be able to access the data as I like.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: By "list of dynamic objects" you mean `List<dynamic>`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic` can mean different things. What you need to look at is what the objects *actually are*. Likely options:

- a regular type (perhaps generated on the fly) with properties / fields per column - in which case reflection will work
- a meta-type provider which also implements a dictionary index (check for `IDictionary<string,object>` etc) - in which case cast as the dictionary and access the keys
- a meta-type provider which does not provide a dictionary - in which case this is... problematic, but which can sometimes be done via the dynamic meta object api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicmetaobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This helped me locate the type of object and how to handle it.